# web page with react displays a blank page?

Tags: reactjs, header

I'm a React beginner. The website gives a blank page. It seems that doesn't read the component `<Header>` in App.js or the component `<App />` in index.js file.

Where do you think the problem is?

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";
import "remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```js
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";

function App() {
  return ( <Header /> );
};

export default App;
```

Header.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import "../../styles/header.css";
import logo from "../../assets/img/dumble.png";

const Header = () => {
  return (
  <Header>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="nav_wrapper">
        {/*=================Logo================= */}
        <div className="logo">
          <div className="logo_img">
            <img src={logo} alt="" srcSet="" />
          </div>

          <h2>Fitbodyyyyyyyyyyyy</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Header>
 );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: If there is an error, it usually appears in browser console. Open it

Comment: You're using your `Header` component in the `Header`?

Comment: RubenSmn Thank you very much. It works now (I removed the Header tag from Header.jsx) . I was just following a React tutorial.  It is hard to find a working tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the return with () like the code below

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Header>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="nav_wrapper">
          {/*=================Logo================= */}
          <div className="logo">
            <div className="logo_img">
              <img src={logo} alt="" srcSet="" />
            </div>
            <h2>Fitbodyyyyyyyyyyyy</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Header>
  );
};
```